# Angular 6 View in Tabs

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any way I can work with Angular 6 so I can open Views in Tab mode?
I need to create an application that will have multiple tabs and when I open it they will be in memory while I'm browsing other tabs without losing the information.

I'm using materializecss.com

Comment: materializecss supports Tabs Component. You can dynamically create tab. https://materializecss.com/tabs.html. Usually Tab will maintain the data in memory.

Comment: What do you mean by tabs? A new navigator tab? Or a UI component that implements tabs?

Comment: I do not know how to associate Abas with the Routes. I would like it when clicking a link in the route dynamically create a tab with the view of that route.

(Osakr) UI component that implements tabs!

Answer (score 0):

Angular is used to create Single Page Application, so opening your link in a separate tab will load all your application for the second time.
However, you can share your data between tabs using `localStorage`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Also, you can use SharedWorker to provide 'between tab' communications

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker